# creating multiple objects of UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to give zoom effect to the iPhone camera image while capturing the photo. The zoom effect should be for particular part of the current image. This effect should be before capturing the image.

For the sample I create the two objects of UIImagePickerController, the code is below

.h file

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker_obj1,imagePicker_obj2;
UIScrollView *scrollView_obj1,*scrollView_obj;
```

.m file

```
imagePicker_obj1 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

imagePicker_obj2 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

imagePicker_obj1.delegate = self;

imagePicker_obj2.delegate = self;

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
        imagePicker_obj1.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
                imagePicker_obj2.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
}
    else
        exit(1);

    scrollView_obj1 = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0, 250.0, 200.0, 200.0)];

    [window addSubview:scrollView_obj1];

    scrollView_obj1.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imagePicker_obj1.view.frame.size.width, imagePicker_obj1.view.frame.size.height);

    scrollView_obj1.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
    scrollView_obj1.minimumZoomScale = 0.75;
    scrollView_obj1.clipsToBounds = YES;
    scrollView_obj1.delegate = self;
    [scrollView_obj1 addSubview:imagePicker_obj1.view];

    scrollView_obj = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0, 0.0, 200.0, 200.0)];

    [window addSubview:scrollView_obj];
    [scrollView_obj setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    scrollView_obj.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imagePicker_obj2.view.frame.size.width, imagePicker_obj2.view.frame.size.height);
    scrollView_obj.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
    scrollView_obj.minimumZoomScale = 0.75;
    scrollView_obj.clipsToBounds = YES;
    scrollView_obj.delegate = self;
       [scrollView_obj addSubview:imagePicker_obj2.view];
```

After this I expect that the two different objects of `UIImagePickerController` give me same output and the content of the two scroll views will be same.
But I got the output from only one object of `UIImagePickerController` and the other is blank.

Can someone explain what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second UIImagePickerController wasn't able to grab the camera because the first had an exclusive lock on it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have one camera, i would expect only one `UIImagePickerController` controller to work in this case.